# In Swift, when using dataTaskWithRequest the completionHandler returns a nil NSURLResponse when the request times out

Tags: ios, swift

When I post data to a service, the request is normally fine, but if it takes too long and times out, in the completion handler, I get NSURLResponse as nil even though it should never return nil.

I'm using Swift 1.1, here's an example of how I'm doing this:

```
func postX(actionKey:String, postData:AnyObject, callBack:((data:NSData?, resp: NSURLResponse) -> Void)?) -> Void
{
    var mreq = createRequest(actionKey, method: "POST", https: true, json: true)
    if (self.dataTask != nil)
    {
        self.dataTask?.cancel()
    }
    var err: NSError?
    mreq.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postData, options: nil, error: &err)
    self.dataTask = self.getSession().dataTaskWithRequest(mreq, completionHandler: { (data:NSData!, resp: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        Dlog.log("response: \(resp)")  //Prints out: response: nil
        if (error != nil)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
        }
    })
    if (self.dataTask != nil)
    {
        self.dataTask!.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `response` can't be `nil`? The type `NSURLResponse!` certainly suggests that can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSURLResponse` reference in the `completionHandler` block of `dataTaskWithRequest` is an optional (meaning that it *can* be `nil`). If the request times out, you'd expect it to be `nil` (because you presumably have not yet received any response).

I would suggest changing the `NSURLResponse` parameter of your `callback` closure to be an optional as well, just like `dataTaskWithRequest`. (I might return the optional `NSError`, too, so you can check for particular errors.) And you can detect timeout errors by looking for `NSURLErrorTimedOut`.

For example:

```
func postX(actionKey: String, postData: AnyObject, callBack: (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let request = createRequest(actionKey, method: "POST", https: true, json: true)

    dataTask?.cancel()   // note, we don't need `if` clause, as the `?` does everything for us

    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postData, options: [])

    let task = getSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        callBack(data, response, error)
    }

    task.resume()

    dataTask = task
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
postX(actionKey, postData: postData) { data, response, error in

    // handle response however you want

    // did it time out?

    if error?.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error?.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
        print("timed out") // note, `response` is likely `nil` if it timed out
    }

}
```

---

For the sake of completeness, the Swift 3 implementation might look like:

```
func postX(actionKey: String, postData: AnyObject, callBack: (Data?, URLResponse?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    var request = createRequest(actionKey: actionKey, method: "POST", https: true, json: true)

    dataTask?.cancel()   // note, we don't need `if` clause, as the `?` does everything for us

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postData, options: [])

    let task = getSession().dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        callBack(data, response, error)
    }

    task.resume()

    dataTask = task
}

func createRequest(actionKey: String, method: String, https: Bool, json: Bool) -> URLRequest {
    var request = URLRequest(url: ...)
    ...
    return request
}
```

And it would be called like:

```
postX(actionKey: actionKey, postData: postData) { data, response, error in

    // handle response however you want

    // did it time out?

    if error?.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error?.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
        print("timed out") // note, `response` is likely `nil` if it timed out
    }

}
```

Comment: When I used it     mreq.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postData, options: nil, error: &err)
 it give Extra Argument error

Comment: Yes, that was written for Swift 1. I've updated it for Swift 2.